# I want to round line items of orders and then sum the aggregate of the rounded values. Is it possible to round line items UP and then SUM them?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, rounding, ceil

Essentially the query works like this:

```
Select Sum(Ceiling((Exp_Cart)*Exp_Qty) from Table_X where Item in ('3')
```

I am receiving an error in my query and wondering if there is a better way to approach this.

The situation is I need to count whole cartons, and a lot of our data has cartons in fractions / sometimes we sell at quantities that result in partial cartons. For capacity purposes, we always round up.

```
Select Sum(Ceiling((Exp_Cart)*Exp_Qty) from Table_X where Item in ('3')
```

I expect it to round up IE:

```
Carton = 0.25
Quantity = 4
Multiply gives me 1 carton
```

Sometimes we have orders of odd quantities which leads to partial cartons

```
Carton = 0.25
Quantity = 5
Multiply now gives me 1.25, which I want to round up to 2.
```

We then need to sum up all of the quantities to provide the correct carton-level information.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Your logic looks OK. Please provide sample data, you current query results and the results that you would like to see.

Comment: You're missing a `)` character to terminate the `SUM` expression.